# Calling php functions using pthread in C

Tags: php, c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I need to multithread a php function but when I call a php function I get this error "Safari Can’t Open the Page"
`Safari can’t open the page “‎localhost/home.php” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.`

I have this lines in my php file

```
<?php
echo "Hello World","<br>";
open_thread("hello");

function hello() {
     echo "Hello World";
}
```

When I remove `hello` from `open_thread("hello");`, it simply outputs this warning:
`Warning: open_thread() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Users/username/Sites/home.php on line 3`

This also happens when I call C function which has output in it, when I remove outputs from the function server works and displays nothing.

The problem occurs here `pthread_join(tid, NULL);`

Here is my C codes

```
PHP_FUNCTION(open_thread)
{

    zval *threaded_func;
    zend_string *func_name;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &threaded_func) != SUCCESS) {
        return;
    }


    if (Z_TYPE_P(threaded_func) != IS_NULL) 
    {
        if (!zend_is_callable(threaded_func, 0, &func_name TSRMLS_CC)) 
        {
            php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "’%s’ is not a valid read callback", func_name);
            efree(func_name);
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
        efree(func_name);
    }


    pthread_t tid;
    zend_printf("Starting..\n");
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *) threaded_func, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    zend_printf("Finished\n");
}
```

**The Question**
Is it a thread safe issue? how do I fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest you remove any browser influences first and instead use the CLI SAPI for now. It's also unclear how this relates to the C code. Note that PHP's "pthreads" is something different than C's pthreads (a.k.a. POXIX threads).

Comment: PHP's "pthreads" is written in  C's pthreads using POXIX's <pthead.h> library and that is what I am trying to achieve myself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Threading in PHP... that's just wrong. I'm not against threads in any way, but for a language like PHP, they're off-limits because: A) There's no need for them in PHP. If you need threads, you're probably tackling something that requires more than PHP. B) A lot of PHP dev's would create horrible code if you give them threading. Protect the world from awful code, and protect bad devs from hurting their own sanity. C) I prefer threading in Go (but that's just me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can be built to support multi threaded SAPI's - ZTS mode - however, it's important to realize that the memory model used is share nothing.

In a shared nothing model, each thread has a different interpreter (compiler, executor, all module globals, all user code, the whole lot).

This means various things:

- Code compiled for thread A cannot be executed by thread B. Thread B must copy code from thread A, carry out something like `pass_two` and execute the copy of the code.
- Code copied from thread A that references objects, resources, or hashtables, may (will) break without proper preparation and or appropriate object handlers.

Simply starting a thread and attempting to call into Zend is doomed to fail, as it ignores the shared nothing nature of PHP.

The flow of new threads needs to be something like:

```
void routine(void *thing) {
    ts_resource(0);

    php_request_startup();

    /* do stuff */

    php_request_shutdown();

    ts_free_thread();
}
```

- `ts_resource`: this initializes TSRM in the new thread, in turn initializing some of Zend
- `php_request_startup`: initializes the rest of everything, among other things runs `RINIT` for all modules
- `php_request_shutdown`: this runs `RSHUTDOWN`, generally cleans up
- `ts_free_thread`: optionally free, would otherwise happen at process shutdown (when TSRM is finally shutdown)

As it is, the example flow would also fail, if it tries to call user code compiled by (for) another thread: After request startup and before you can call user code you need to copy the code into the current context first.

The fine detail of how any of this works in the real world can be found in the pthreads extension sources.

Comment: Thanks Joe, your answer is much appreciated!.

Comment: I got this warning and error.  I am using clang compiler, should I install gcc?-----------/Users/username/terminal/src/php/ext/pthread/php_pthread.c:30:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'php_request_shutdown' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    php_request_shutdown();
    ^
/Users/username/terminal/src/php/ext/pthread/php_pthread.c:32:20: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
    ts_free_thread(0);

Comment: Was mistake in code ... the code was example flow, not ready to compile ;)